# Error 405 metodo DELETE o POST con ajax en laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax, sweetalert

estoy con jquery, ajax y sweetalert2, este ejemplo lo implemente en un ejercicio en java, pero ahora me toca implementarlo con **laravel** pero no me funciona perfecto como en java.

Si bien cumple la función de eliminar, esta en vez de presentarme el mensaje de éxito me presenta el mensaje de error, siendo que el método funciona ingresa al controlador y ejecuta el destroy que solo cambia el estado a inactivo del usuario.

```
<table id="tabla" class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Correo Electrónico</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
                <th>Última Visita</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Opciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->job}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->last_visit}}</td>
                <td>
                    @switch($user->status)
                    @case(0)
                    <span class="badge badge-pill border border-danger text-danger">Inactivo</span>
                    @break
                    @case(1)
                    <span class="badge badge-pill border border-success text-success">Activo</span>
                    @break
                    @endswitch
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="flex align-items-center list-user-action">
                        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar" data-original-title="Editar"
                            href="users/{{$user->id}}/edit"><i class="ri-pencil-line"></i></a>
                        <a id="eliminar" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"
                            data-original-title="Eliminar"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line"></i></a>
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="{{$user->id}}" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Me tira error 405 según la red por el método, si ocupo DELETE o POST sigue sin visualizar el mensaje de éxito y en la consola tira error de método que solo soporta GET|PUT|ATCH|DELETE|HEAD**

```
$('table #eliminar').click(function(){
        let id = $(this).parent().find('#id').val();
        console.log(id);
        let nombre = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(1).text();
        let apellido = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(2).text();
        console.log(nombre);

        Swal.fire({
            title: "¿Estás seguro?",
            text: "¿Seguro de querer dar de baja al usuario "+ nombre +" "+ apellido +"?",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Si, eliminar!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            reverseButtons: true
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                eliminarUser(id);
            }
        })
    });

    function eliminarUser(id){
        var urlGlobal = "{{url('/')}}";
        var urlDestroyUser  = urlGlobal+"/users/"+id;
        var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
        var data = {id:id,_token:token};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: urlDestroyUser,
            data: data,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){ //No ingresa al success siendo que la opción fue 
                Swal.fire({
                    title: "Eliminación exitosa!",
                    icon: "success"
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                })
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                Swal.fire(
                'Error',
                'Ha ocurrido un problema',
                'error'
                )
            }
        })
    }
```

**Controlador**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            
            $user = User::where('id','=',$id)->firstOrFail();
            $user->status = 0;
            $user->save();

            return redirect('/users');
        } catch (ModeNotFoundException $e) {
            return redirect('/users');
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Rutas**

```
Route::resource('/users','UserController');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como tienes tu archivo de rutas?

Comment: @CesarRomero hay actualize el post con al información de rutas y controlador pero lo tengo Route::resource('/users','UserController'); que según la imagen sería users/{users}

Comment: @CesarRomero porque en si el metodo funciona, me hace el cambio de estado pero al ejecutar el success o error me toma siempre el error, si presiono F5 y veo el dato veo que si cambio de estado al usuario.

Comment: tu problema esta en que realizas el envio con AJAX y tu response en la función Destroy es una redirección

Comment: Mira no se si esto era el error pero cambie en el controlador el return view por return response()->json(['mensaje'=>''elimino']) y me empezo a tirar el mensaje de exito

Comment: Exacto, ahí estaba tu problema. AJAX espera una respuesta `XML`, `JSON` u otro y tu tenias una redirección a otra vista